# UIBarButtonItem depending on presentation. Swift3

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uinavigationitem

I am facing a problem, because there are two ways how do I display my `ViewController`.

1. First way is `performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)`

It works fine because then I have this back button in my `navigationItem`:

[image]

2. Then I use this code to present the same `ViewController` (from another `viewController` than in the first case):

   ```
       let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navViewController") as! UINavigationController
       let vc = navVC.topViewController as! ViewController             
       self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

but then I do not have any back button in my `ViewController`.

**My question is:** How can I keep my `backButton (exactly how it is)` when I use this function: `performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)` , but add button (can look different) when I use this function: `self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

**Note:** In my case 1 my segue is connected right to `ViewController` , but in case 2 I present `UINavigationController` and `ViewController` is `embed in` in this `UINavigationController`.

**Edit:** I tried this code, but it always prints: `"1........."`:

```
if self.presentingViewController != nil {
            print("1..........")
        } else if self.navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == self.navigationController  {
            return print("2.........")
        } else if self.tabBarController?.presentingViewController is UITabBarController {
            return print("3........")
        }
```

And also this code prints:`"Else.............."` :

```
let isPresentingInAddMealMode = presentedViewController is UINavigationController

if isPresentingInAddMealMode {
    print("FirstOption......................")

} else {
    print("Else......................")

}
```

If you need more info just let me know.
Thank you very much.

Comment: When you present a ViewController as a modal, you need to add the button yourself to the navigationItem.

Comment: I know, but when I added a button navigationItem my "<Back" disappears and there is only button which I added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it!! I put `restorationIdentifier` to  my root `navigationController` and then I just check if that is `navigationController` with my `restorationIdentifier` like this:

```
    if self.navigationController?.restorationIdentifier == "navViewController"{
        let leftItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .stop, target: self, action: #selector(goBack))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem //Adds item if id is navViewController
    }else{
       self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil //removes it and keeps "<Back"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check presentedViewController and add back button as below .

```
if ([self presentedViewController]) {
        // add your back button item here
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this option but it always adds backbuttonItem, but I want to add it only in one case :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login") as! LoginView
let customNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
customNavigation.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
self.present(customNavigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Login"
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.backButton))

}
func backButton() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Try to set Image in UIBarButtonItem